# Facebook comments and likes problem

Tags: javascript, facebook, comments, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I would like to know when a user leaves a comment or likes a page, so I used

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comments.add', function(response) {
    alert('comment add');       
}); 
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.remove', function(response) {
    alert('comment remove');
});
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
    alert('like add');
});
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(response) {
    alert('like remove');
});
```

Only 'comments.add' is working which is different from the [facebook doc](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/), so I guess there are another names for the other events?
The like button doesn't work at all it gives the following error

> Website inaccessible  The page at http://localhost.local/interviews/view/2 could not be reached.

I am using:

```
<fb:comments numposts="5" notify="true" width="450" height="500" class="fb_iframe_widget">/fb:comments>
```

as it is shown in the url, I am working on localhost environment, is this the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, if Facebook's crawler can't reach your page, it can't be liked. I'm not sure the comments plugin has that level of verification so I think the comments plugin may still work

Comment: thanx I will try to deploy public and test it .. and what about FB.Event.subscribe('comment.remove'), do you know how to subscribe to removal of comment?

Comment: There shouldn't be anything special needed, the event should fire when someone removes their comment from the plugin - if it doesn't, please file a bug report at http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/ and we can take a look